# airtable python wrapper - passing API key not working

Tags: python, airtable

I'm trying to use airtable-python-wrapper but it's not accepting the API key when passed, as explained here:
https://airtable-python-wrapper.readthedocs.io/en/master/authentication.html

Code below:

```
from airtable import Airtable
base_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
table_name = 'MyTable'

airtable = Airtable(base_key, table_name, api_key='xxxxxxxxxxx')
airtable.get_all()
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: This code is correct -- I was using the database name and not table name to access. The database is specified via the "base_key". Usage was not clear to me at the time.